# Error casting in C#

Tags: c#, casting, compiler-errors

I'm getting the following error

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.String'.

in the code:

```
public static List<Category> getPopularCategories() {
    clsCityPageDataContext cox = new clsCityPageDataContext();
    var cats = from cat in cox.Categories select cat;
    return cats.ToList<Category>().GetRange(0,10);
}
```

Comment: Could you post the definition of Category?

Comment: The error must be occuring in the `clsCityPageDataContext` object somewhere. Either in the constructor or the enumerator on the `Categories` field/property.

Comment: side note: `var cats = from cat in cox.Categories select cat;` is redundant; `var cats = cox.Categories` does the exact same thing.

Comment: Yes what is the definitiopn of Category? and what type is clsCityPageDataContext.Categories?

Comment: look at here....
[System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="cpDB")]
public partial class clsCityPageDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
{.......................also....public System.Data.Linq.Table<Category> Categories
 {
        
  get
  {
           
   return this.GetTable<Category>();
  }
 }

Answer (score 1):

The problem is:

```
var cats = from cat in cox.Categories select cat;
return cats.ToList<Category>().GetRange(0,10);
```

replace with:

```
var cats = from cat in cox.Categories select cat;
return cats.ToList().GetRange(0,10);
```

Comment: great that worked.now the isssue is ..........System.IO.FileLoadException: Cannot create/shadow copy 'RJS.Web.WebControl.PopCalendar' when that file already exists.....Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'RJS.Web.WebControl.PopCalendar' could not be loaded

Comment: Thats another error related to a Reference to a ToolKit, i REcommend you to create new Post ;-)

Comment: Yes this code worked for first time but now again faced the same problem....can you please suggest any other solution?